# Angular UI Bootstrap Tabset: Prevent tab switching

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, tabs, angular-ui-router

I am having issues to try to prevent tab switch.
This is the plunker.
http://plnkr.co/edit/v1i1cmBzqGo7hmWkhIh4?p=preview
When user click the 'Alert' Tab, I want to do some conditional test, and prevents that 'Alert' tab is not selected.
How can I do that?
And another question is when each tab is associated with ui state.
And when the tab is changed the ui state is also changing.
I want to prevent that and I made this code.

```
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart',
        function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams){
          event.preventDefault();

          destinationTab.active = false;
          sourceTab.active = true;
        });
```

Then after this code the original tab is not active.

Answer (score 0):

I came across this issue too and wrote a little directive to fix it.  It's super hacky, but basically it looks for all tab header links, adds a click event, flips the event order of each link to get our event to fire before angulars, then use promises to allow for a controller method to control tab switching.  This should work with their select/deselect attributes as well.

Directive:

```
.directive('tabPrevent', ['$q', '$timeout', function ($q, $timeout) {
    'use strict';

    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            var tabHeadings = element.find('ul li a'),
                  tabEvents = [];

            if (attrs.tabPrevent) {
                tabHeadings.bind('click', function (e) {
                    e.stopImmediatePropagation();

                    var deferred = $q.defer(),
                          self = this,
                          tabIndex = -1

                    // find tab index for tabEvents reference
                    angular.forEach(tabHeadings, function (tab, index) {
                        if (tab === self) {
                            tabIndex = index;
                        }
                    });

                    // call controller method, passing promise
                    scope.$eval(attrs.tabPrevent + '(deferred)', { deferred: deferred });

                    deferred.promise.then(function (success) {
                        // initiate call to next event in array, which switches the tab
                        $timeout(function() {
                            tabEvents[tabIndex].click[1].handler(e);
                        });
                    });
                });

                // flip event order to make our event fire before angular's
                angular.forEach(tabHeadings, function (tabHeading) {
                    var clickEvents = $._data(tabHeading, "events");
                    tabEvents.push(clickEvents);    // save list of click events
                    clickEvents.click.unshift(clickEvents.click.pop()); // reverse events
                });
            }
        }
    };

}]);
```

HTML:

```
        <tabset tab-prevent="checkTab">
            <tab heading="{{tabs[0].title}}" active="tabs[0].active">Tab 1</tab>
            <tab heading="{{tabs[1].title}}" active="tabs[1].active">Tab 2</tab>
            <tab heading="{{tabs[2].title}}" active="tabs[2].active">Tab 3</tab>
        </tabset>
```

Controller:

```
    $scope.checkTab = function (deferred) {
        if ($scope.form && $scope.form.$dirty) {
            deferred.reject();  // stops tab switch
        } else {
            deferred.resolve();  // allows tab swtich
        }
    };
```